# What does it mean for Mach ports to be "globally unique"?

Tags: mach, gnu-hurd

I read [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/microkernel/mach/port.html) in the GNU Hurd docs that Mach ports are "globally unique." I know that one of the design goals for Mach was for it to be easily used in distributed computing environments, so does this mean Mach ports are globally unique *across all Mach systems* at any given point in time? This would mean that Mach ports can be used as references to objects that live on remote Mach systems, which is convenient. But how is this implemented?

Or does this statement mean Mach ports are only guaranteed to be globally unique *on a single Mach system* at any given point in time?

Comment: I've done some Mach development and always understood it to mean globally unique on the current host, i.e. unique across processes. I didn't design Mach so I can't say for sure they *aren't* unique across all hosts everywhere, but in this case I believe they are just system-unique.

Comment: @par Thanks for your input! I'll work under the same assumption (i.e., that ports are unique on the current system only) for now unless something convinces me otherwise.